# Initialization of class attributes in dataclasses with inheritence

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have a collection of dataclasses that inherit from each other. These classes create scaffolds that can be implemented to create concrete/final classes.

I have a `Base` class that defines the lowest/most simple required structure. I have an `Intermediate` class that defines extra behavior on top of the `Base` class. Finally, I have a `Concrete` class that implements the Intermediate class.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Base:
    name: str
    description: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Intermediate(Base):
    special_field_needed_for_intermediate: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Concrete(Intermediate):
    special_field_needed_for_intermediate = "hehe"
    name = "HeHe"
    description = "hehe wowee"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Concrete())
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: Concrete.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'description', and 'special_field_needed_for_intermediate'
```

I can fix this by calling the super constructor in the `Concrete` class, but that feels rather un-pythonic/not very dataclass-esque:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Concrete(Intermediate):
    special_field_needed_for_intermediate = "hehe"
    name = "HeHe"
    description = "hehe wowee"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            self.name,
            self.description,
            self.special_field_needed_for_intermediate,
        )
```

Is there a way I can pass these attributes up the chain, without manually invoking the parent constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataclasses use a bit of metaclass magic to function. Neither `Base` nor `Intermediate` define any *class* attributes; the metaclass uses the annotated names in the `class` statement to generate code that defines *instance* attributes.

When you define `Concrete`, you *do* define some class attributes, but those have nothing to do with the instance attributes that `Concrete.__init__` would define.  Their values can only be used during attribute *lookup* once you have an instance of `Concrete`; they will not be used for initializing the instance attributes via `__init__`.

This lookup behavior is why your workaround works: `Concrete.__init__` doesn't require any arguments, instead using (for example) `self.name` (which falls back to `Concrete.name`, because the instance attribute does not yet exist) to provide the argument to `Intermediate.__init__`, which *does* create (via `Base.__init__`) the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code seems to work just fine when you including type annotations in your `Concrete` class:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Base:
    name: str
    description: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Intermediate(Base):
    special_field_needed_for_intermediate: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Concrete(Intermediate):
    name: str = "HeHe"
    description: str = "hehe wowee"
    special_field_needed_for_intermediate: str = "hehe"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Concrete())
```

Running this produces:

```
Concrete(name='HeHe', description='hehe wowee', special_field_needed_for_intermediate='hehe')
```

Comment: Hmm, this is great, but also feels a little flaky/spooky. Are there any docs I can read as to why this works?

Comment: I can't point at any particular documentation, but note that the [`dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) does require type annotations on attributes in order to recognize them as dataclass attributes. Your `Concrete` class was syntactically different from your other two classes, which were correctly typed.